# magento 2 - downloadable file link is not working

Tags: downloadable, magento2.1.5

I am facing issues about downloadable link. The download able link from email after purchase documents is taking to login page.

It is not downloading the product.

I have tried many solution but nothing work.

can any one suggest me any solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading to magento 2.1.6 fix my issue.